# jQuery: Select child of child of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

**HTML:**

```
<form id=f1>
  <div>
    <input id=text>
  </div>
</form>

<form id=f2>
  <div>
    <input id=text>
  </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  var id=$(this).attr('id');
  var text=$('#'+id+'#text').val();
  alert(text);
});
```

**Result:**

> Undefined

I need to select the input but I dont know how,

This question is Corrected

Comment: add space `' #text'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between the parts of the selector:

```
var text = $("#" + id + " #text").val();
```

But there's no need to use the ID at all:

```
var text = $(this).find("#text").val();
```

Also, IDs are supposed to be unique, you can't have `id="text"` multiple times. You should use `class="text"`, and then it would be:

```
var text = $(this).find(".text").val();
```

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
  var text=$(this).find(".text").val();
  console.log(text);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id=f1>
  <div>
    <input class=text>
  </div>
</form>

<form id=f2>
  <div>
    <input class=text>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Since it's an input field in a form that's being submitted, I think changing `id` to `name` would be more appropriate than `class`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Since it's not being submitted normally, the name is not significant. And name selectors are more verbose.

Comment: still Undefined

Comment: @MedAmine I've added an executable snippet, it works.

Comment: TY i see it but didnt work on my code i will try again and again until work, thank u for help

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use multiple id's! ID should be unique.

In your example, you pass wrong selector to jQuery function, it should be:
`var text = $('#' + id + ' #text');` (missing space between selectors)